# How to access Beaker web app

Tags: beaker-testing

When accessing Beaker via http://$MYSERVER/bkr/, I ran into a 500 Internal Server Error with the following logs in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log beaker. How do I fix this?

```
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.566934 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] [2018-07-18 12:50:39,566] ERROR in app: Exception on /bkr/ server.webpath = "/bkr/" [GET]
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.566989 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.566998 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567002 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567005 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1634, in full_dispatch_request
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567007 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567012 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1660, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567016 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     func()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567019 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bkr/server/wsgi.py", line 119, in init
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567021 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     assets.build_assets()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567024 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bkr/server/assets.py", line 169, in build_assets
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567027 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     bundle.build()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567029 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 682, in build
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567032 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     disable_cache=disable_cache))
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567034 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 619, in _build
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567054 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     force, disable_cache=disable_cache, extra_filters=extra_filters)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567057 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 543, in _merge_and_apply
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567060 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     kwargs=item_data)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567062 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 276, in apply
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567065 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     return self._wrap_cache(key, func)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567067 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 218, in _wrap_cache
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567070 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     content = func().getvalue()
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567072 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 251, in func
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567075 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     getattr(filter, type)(data, out, **kwargs_final)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567077 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/less.py", line 139, in input
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567080 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     self._apply_less(_in, out, source_path)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567082 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/less.py", line 131, in _apply_less
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567085 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     self.subprocess(args, out, in_)
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567087 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/__init__.py", line 527, in subprocess
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567090 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]     proc.returncode, stdout, stderr))
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567095 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] FilterError: less: subprocess returned a non-success result code: 1, stdout=, stderr=\x1b[31mNameError: #grid > .core > .span is undefined\x1b[39m\x1b[31m in \x1b[39mbootstrap/less/navbar.less\x1b[90m on line 199, column 3:\x1b[39m
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567099 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] \x1b[90m198 .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {\x1b[39m
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567101 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] 199   \x1b[7m\x1b[31m\x1b[1m#\x1b[22mgrid > .core > .span(@gridColumns);\x1b[39m\x1b[27m
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567104 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010] \x1b[90m200 }\x1b[39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567106 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]
[Wed Jul 18 12:50:39.567109 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3400] [remote 10.38.33.62:61010]
```

Comment: Did you search Bugzilla? It's a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369590

Comment: This kind of question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow, which is for programming Q&A... If you need help with Beaker deployment, your best bet is to ask your questions on the [project mailing list](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/beaker-devel@lists.fedorahosted.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I tried sign up on the mailing list but it said the sign up is currently closed. So how can I ask my question?